# How to connect MYSQL Data Base to my Django app via an ssh

Tags: mysql, django, ssh

How to connect my Django app to MySQL DB via ssh. I have a MySQL DB hosted in Namecheap. I can connect to it via ssh using a terminal, is there any way I can do that??

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to set up an SSH tunnel.

https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/tunneling/example